# How to launch default program for file from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, macros

I would like to have a Powershell function that opens whatever Visual Studio Solution (.sln) file happens to be in the current directory.  Manually, I do this:

1. Type *.sln
2. Press Tab to expand it to the full file name
3. Hit Enter

With the Powershell function, call it "z", I would just type "z" then Enter and it would open whatever .sln file is there.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I hear you but for a question like this I myself don't find it very useful when other post one liners that don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code working according to PowerShell logic. It finds (first) *.sln file in current directory and opens it using default OS action.

```
Function Z {
    Invoke-Item (Get-Item *.sln | Select -First 1)
}
```